# iis 7.5 wont serve up korean characters in my classic asp application

Tags: iis, encoding, asp, utf-8

I have a classic ASP website hosted in IIS 7.5 - using a classic application pool pipeline. I have all my .Net Globalization settings set to UTF-8 encoding. However when my site outputs Korean characters that it is getting directly from a database, the characters are corrupted when they are output to the web request.

What else might I need to do in order to allow my classic ASP site and IIS 7.5 to handle Korean characters correctly?

Here's what is being pulled from the database - and seems to be stored correctly in teh db: 크기변환_01[3].jpg
But this is what it looks like when it is output from the server: ????_01[3].jpg

Comment: It means something in the line is missing UTF-8 characters. What about the browser?

Comment: I can confirm that it is not the browser. The output from the server is garbage.